# SQLite3 how to compare indices to lists

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I'm using `Pandas` and `SQLite3` and have a `SQL table` called `Environment` with two saved Environments. Each of those Environments contain of 4 `meas_dev_ids` and 4 `subset_id`, see picture. The important difference between the two is that the order of the `subset_ids` is different in the second one.

[image: SQL Table called Environment]

**Question**: With what query would I get the id of the first Environment if these two lists are given:

- meas_dev_ids = (1,2,3,4)
- subset_id = (a,b,c,d)

With the lists

- meas_dev_ids = (1,2,3,4)
- subset_id = (b,a,c,d)

I would like it to output the id of the second Environment.

The query I'm using at the moment is:

```
'SELECT DISTINCT id FROM environment a 
WHERE meas_dev_ids IN (1, 2, 3, 4) 
Group by id 
having count(*) = 4 and not exists 
(SELECT * FROM environment b WHERE meas_dev_ids NOT IN (1, 2, 3, 4) and a.id = b.id)'
```

With this query I can get the Environment which has exactly the meas_dev_ids (1,2,3,4).
It is however not able to discern between the two Environments in the table above.

**Important notes:**

- The Environment table can contain Environments with an arbitrary
  number of `subset_id` (they don't have to be of length 4).
- With the query I would like to get the Environment id with the exact same composition as mentioned in the lists provided. For example if I'm looking for the Environment with meas_dev_ids = (3,4) and subset_id = (c,d), I want the result to be None (in this case), because both saved Environments have more entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `GROUP_CONCAT()` window function:

```
SELECT id
FROM (
  SELECT id, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY meas_dev_ids DESC) rn, 
         GROUP_CONCAT(meas_dev_ids) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY meas_dev_ids) meas_dev_ids,
         GROUP_CONCAT(subset_id) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY meas_dev_ids) subset_ids
  FROM Environment
)
WHERE rn = 1 AND meas_dev_ids = ? AND subset_ids = ?
```

Replace the `?` placeholders with the `meas_dev_id`s and `subset_id`s that you search for, as comma separated strings, like `'1,2,3,4'` and `'a,b,c,d'`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=126b236f9fa9959d5cfbb4376a58f108).

*Note*: If it returns a `syntax error near "("`, update `sqlite3` by downloading the sqlite3.dll from [sqlite.org](https://sqlite.org/download.html) and replacing it in the Python\DLLs folder.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer including this nice demo. This looked very promising. Sadly I could not get it to work because it always raises a syntax error near "(". I think it's because of the window function `PARTITION BY`. Is it possible that SQLite3 in Python 3.6 uses a SQL version that does not support this? (I'm still new to Python and SQL)

Comment: You are using a version of SQLite from 2008 while the current version of SQLite is 3.34.1 (2021-01-20). Window functions are supported since version 3.25.0 (2018-09-15). I think that it would be better to upgrade.

Comment: You were right, it works perfectly now. Thank you very much, you saved my day. I had so many problems, probably due to this old version. No idea why it didn't install the new version with pip.